# C language: How do I read an input like this "SomeWord(Int)", with no spaces, just a word and then a number inside round brackets

Tags: c, input, format, scanf

I need to take input from the user that is a single line and has 5 values which I extract from that input ('c' needs to be 5). The input is this format: "**word(number) number word sentence**". But the problem is with the "**word(number)**" input area. I cannot get it so that the values are read from that part of the input and stored in command, and num1. Below is the code I tried but it does not seem to be working.

```
c = sscanf (line, "%s(%d) %d %s %128[^\n]", command, num1, num2, message, message2);
```

When I make it so that the user enters "**word (number) number word sentence**" instead, with a space before the brackets, with also changing the code from `%s(%d)` to `%s (%d)`, that seems to work. But I need it without any space between the values `command` and `num1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to exclude the parenthesis from the first string. Assuming the "command" is strictly alphanumeric and underscore, you can do this:

```
c = sscanf(line, "%[_a-zA-Z0-9](%d) %d %s %128[^\n]", command, &num1, &num2, message, message2);
```

Also, you need ampersands on `num1` and `num2`; perhaps those were typos?

For safety, you should put length limits on `command` and `message` as you do for `message2`. Assuming 'char command[21], message[33];`, this would be:

```
"%20[_a-zA-Z0-9](%d) %d %32s %128[^\n]"
```

Comment: You could also do everything but a parens: `sscanf(line, "%[^(](%d) %d %s %128[^\n]"....`

Comment: Yes, but this would allow spaces too.